# How can I select all data from table sales for user

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

Example SQL Table:

```
ID | USER | AMOUNT_SALES | TOTAL
--------------------------------
1  | John | 1500         | 2000 
2  | John | 1400         | 3000  
3  | James| 1200         | 4000   
4  | John | 1100         | 5000   
5  | Anie | 1900         | 8000
```

So I want to

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

and show the results on HTML table using while, but I don't want to repeat the users.

Example table I want to create:

```
User  | Amount Sales  | Total 
-----------------------------
John  | 4000          | 10000
James | 1200          | 4000
Anie  | 1900          | 8000
```

Comment: I think what you require is `GROUP BY` [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)
And then use `SUM` [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT user, 
       sum(amount_sales) as sum_sales, 
       sum(total) as sum_totals
FROM table
group by user
```

Comment: Tnks a lot, i was missing the Group By.

Comment: Now i can't put the result divided by columns. I doing this:

Comment: <td>'.$row['SUM(amount_sales)'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['SUM(total)'].'</td> but the table is blank

Comment: Then you can use `$row['sum_sales']`

Comment: And if i have WHERE clauses in query, like this: SELECT *, sum(valorvendatotal) as sum_valorvendatotal, sum(nrvisitas) as sum_nrvisitas
FROM fichas WHERE vendedor = '$vendedor' OR zona = '$zona' OR cemiterio = '$cemiterio' OR mes_criacao = '$mes' GROUP BY vendedor

Comment: I don't understand the question?

Comment: I have this query: SELECT user, 
       sum(amount_sales) as sum_sales, 
       sum(total) as sum_totals
FROM table WHERE zone='$zone' OR area='$area' OR place = '$place'
GROUP BY user  --- and the sums don't work

Answer (score 2):

SQL GROUP BY Syntax
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

e.g.,
select user, sum(amount) as sum
from table
group by user

Answer (score 1):

Summing the totals and grouping by the user will do what you need:

```
SELECT user, SUM(amount_sales),SUM(total) FROM table GROUP BY user;
```